# Google Sheets Query Select is making an extra empty row

Tags: google-sheets

Both of these are reading right so I have the link and the sheet and all the info correct, it's just outputting a little strange.  I believe it's the same issue on both of them.  Any help much appreciated.

1st issue:

```
=query(importrange("link","b9:d1000"),"Select Col3 where Col1 = '"&C4&"' ")
```

When I do this one it needs two rows.  It puts the value I want in the first one and leaves the second row blank.  As in, if I put anything in the second row, it gives me #REF can't overwrite that cell.

2nd issue:

```
=query(importrange("link","b9:d1000"),"Select max(Col3) where Col1 = '"&C4&"' ")
```

When I do this one It gives me two rows:  the word "max" and then below it the actual max value.  How do I get it to give me just the max value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different issues. In the first, there happen to be two rows that meet the condition in `where`; the second of them has empty Col3. If you want only one result, either revise the `where` condition by adding some additional requirement, or put `limit 1` at the end of query string, to make sure only one row is returned.

```
"Select Col3 where Col1 = '"&C4&"' limit 1"
```

Second issue: "max" is the name given to the output column. This name can be changed to empty string with `label max(Col3) ''`, which will eliminate the cell with the name.

```
"Select max(Col3) where Col1 = '"&C4&"' label max(Col3) ''"
```